# integration of GSM module and Bluetooth using arduino

Tags: bluetooth, gsm

Please help me. There is a conflict when I put GSM and Bluetooth module in one MCU. The problem is when I use the GSM, the Bluetooth will not respond and vice-versa.

Comment: How do you "use the GSM" and what response are you expecting from the Bluetooth module that you didn't get? There's not enough information here to know what's happening.

Comment: actually i cant connect the GSM module to the network and also i cant combine the GSM module and Bluetooth module in one MCU. i'm using arduino uno